# How would I read a file line by line using the MIPS assembly language

Tags: file, io, mips

I was working on a project for my class which requires me to read in from a file line by line. Our end goal is to make a MIPS assembler using the MIPS language, but the problem pertinent to this post is that I cannot read in line by line from the file. I have created this so far as a mechanism to read in information from the file.

```
.data
file_loc: .asciiz "test.asm" #note: when launching from commandline, test.asm should be within the same folder as Mars.jar
buffer: .space 1024 #buffer of 1024
new_line: .asciiz "\n"  #where would I actually use this?

#error strings
readErrorMsg: .asciiz "\nError in reading file\n"
openErrorMsg: .asciiz "\nError in opening file\n"

.text
main:
jal openFile
j endProgram

openFile:
#Open file for for reading purposes
li $v0, 13          #syscall 13 - open file
la $a0, file_loc        #passing in file name
li $a1, 0               #set to read mode
li $a2, 0               #mode is ignored
syscall
bltz $v0, openError     #if $v0 is less than 0, there is an error found
move $s0, $v0           #else save the file descriptor

#Read input from file
li $v0, 14          #syscall 14 - read filea
move $a0, $s0           #sets $a0 to file descriptor
la $a1, buffer          #stores read info into buffer
li $a2, 1024            #hardcoded size of buffer
syscall             
bltz $v0, readError     #if error it will go to read error

li $v0, 4
la $a0, buffer
syscall

#Close the file 
li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file
jr $ra

openError:
la $a0, openErrorMsg
li $v0, 4
syscall
j endProgram

readError:
la $a0, readErrorMsg
li $v0, 4
syscall
j endProgram


endProgram:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

The problem is reading in a file will read in as many bytes that can be held within the buffer (1024), rather than the line.

For example reading in a file named test.asm with the following data:

```
test abc abc abc

test2 1231 123 123
```

will yield an output of:

```
test abc abc abc

test2 1231 123 123
```

Where as I am hoping to read in one line at at time:

```
test abc abc abc
```

I know that reducing the buffer size will help limit this information, but in the case of a long line of input it may cause some problems. I was hoping to see if anyone knows how to read in a certain amount from the buffer and then split it at the new line indicator (I'm pretty sure its "\n").

Any help/tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So read 1024 (or whatever number) bytes at a time and write a function that returns the next line from the buffer.

Comment: any luck with that?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to read large chunks like you're doing. This is efficient in terms of minimizing syscalls but the code is a bit fussy to write. You'd need a loop to walk over each chunk to locate any newlines and a buffer to store incomplete lines that require multiple reads to build.

A lazy approach that's easier to code is to read the file byte by byte which makes newline detection effortless:

```
# if current byte is a newline, consume line
lb $s4 ($s1)  # load the current byte from the buffer
li $t0 10     # ASCII newline
beq $s4 $t0 consume_line
```

You could use `sbrk` (system call 9) to allocate more memory for the buffer to handle arbitrarily long lines, but for this example I'll assume lines are never longer than 1024 bytes. I leave better error handling, line consumption code and modularity as an exercise in the interest of keeping the example minimal.

You can save this as `read_file_lines.s`, run with `spim -f read_file_lines.s` and it'll print its own source code.

```
.data  
fin: .asciiz "read_file_lines.s"
buffer: .space 1
line: .space 1024
.globl main
.text
main:
    la $s1 buffer
    la $s2 line
    li $s3 0      # current line length

    # open file
    li $v0 13     # syscall for open file
    la $a0 fin    # input file name
    li $a1 0      # read flag
    li $a2 0      # ignore mode 
    syscall       # open file 
    move $s0 $v0  # save the file descriptor 

read_loop:

    # read byte from file
    li $v0 14     # syscall for read file
    move $a0 $s0  # file descriptor 
    move $a1 $s1  # address of dest buffer
    li $a2 1      # buffer length
    syscall       # read byte from file

    # keep reading until bytes read <= 0
    blez $v0 read_done

    # naively handle exceeding line size by exiting
    slti $t0 $s3 1024
    beqz $t0 read_done

    # if current byte is a newline, consume line
    lb $s4 ($s1)
    li $t0 10
    beq $s4 $t0 consume_line

    # otherwise, append byte to line
    add $s5 $s3 $s2
    sb $s4 ($s5)

    # increment line length
    addi $s3 $s3 1

    b read_loop

consume_line:

    # null terminate line
    add $s5 $s3 $s2
    sb $zero ($s5)

    # reset bytes read
    li $s3 0

    # print line (or consume it some other way)
    move $a0 $s2
    li $v0 4
    syscall

    # print newline
    li $a0 10
    li $v0 11
    syscall

    b read_loop

read_done:

    # close file
    li $v0 16     # syscall for close file
    move $a0 $s0  # file descriptor to close
    syscall       # close file

    # exit the program
    li $v0 10
    syscall
```