# How Read file "Comma Separated file" using Mips Assembly line by line then Char by Char and convert it from String of ASCII to Int?

Tags: csv, assembly, buffer, ascii, mips

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9RQg.png)
[the CSV file that i am trying to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWGmQ.png)

I am trying to read a CSV "Comma Separated file" **In Mips assembly language**, as **string of ASCII** then put it in Register or buffer **as Integers** .
If any one had the same problem or can help me with this .

I have tried to read a CSV file, put i couldn't continue .

---

```
.data
    file: .asciiz "helloWorld.csv"   
    .word 0
    buffer: .space 4
.text
main:
    #open file
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, file
    add $a1, $zero, $zero
    add $a2, $zero, $zero
    syscall
    add $s0, $v0, $zero
    #read 4 bytes from file
    li $v0, 14
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    la $a1, buffer
    li $a2, 4
    syscall
    #print
    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, buffer
    syscall

done:
    li $v0, 16
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    syscall

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: It's probably easier to parse the file if you read more than just 4 bytes into your buffer.  Like, a lot more, like 8kiB or something that you can assume is larger than any single line, so you don't have to worry about reading more in the middle of one line.

Comment: Why do you read 4 bytes? It's string values, so they can have any size. You need to read a buffer and keep a pointer to the current line within this buffer. If there is no EOL, move the current line to the beginning of the buffer, and read the next chunk to fill the buffer, so you have always a  complete line. Your CSV code will then have to deal with one line after the other. Depending on the size of your CSV, you can even read the whole file, then you don't have to deal with chunking.

Comment: ultimately you parse the file one byte at a time so other than performance how many you read doesnt matter.   but you would do this in asm the same way you would do it in any other language.  can you show the prototype you wrote in some other language for this task before you started to convert that algorithm to asm?

Comment: Lots of unknowns here. What do the 2,2 on lines one and two mean? The matrix is 3x3, so are these n-1 x m-1? Are the numbers base 2 or 10? Are they always binary 0 and 1? Do you need the whole file in one buffer or are you planning on processing it line by line? If the latter, maybe [How would I read a file line by line using the MIPS assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120501/how-would-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-using-the-mips-assembly-language/65121161#65121161) can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I read a file line by line using the MIPS assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120501/how-would-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-using-the-mips-assembly-language)